# Is it theoretically possible to create a ray of electrons with a photoelectric effect?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, visible-light, electrons, photoelectric-effect

I was just experimenting with old CRT monitors in the last few days and while I did that, I asked myself quite an interesting question: Could the CRT effect in theory be reversed so that beams of light are translated to electron rays?

A CRT screen uses fluorescence for creating diffuse light out of the hitting electrons.
I know that this process is reversible, it's possible to create electric energy in for example photodiodes. But is it possible to do this without a diffusion effect but rather with a beam of multiple electrons which follow along the path of the initial beam of light?

Comment: Florescence doesn't create beams of light: why would its reverse create beams of electrons?

Comment: well, it emits photons, doesn't it? Doesn't this mean this process has to be reversible so electrons are emited if a certain chemical element is hit with photons?

Comment: the photoelectric effect is exactly that, electrons being knocked loose by photons. But it doesn't generate a *ray* of electrons. I think you're taking liberties with the idea of reversibility.